# Can 'who' refer to an inanimate object such as a government body?

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses, collective-nouns, relative-pronouns, animacy

I'm wondering if it is possible to use 'who' in a sentence like this: 'the name of the government body **who** has assigned an identification number to the document.'

Comment: Sure, you’d be in the same company as Shakespeare, Milton, and Wordsworth—all famous writers. You might, however, annoy a few modern complainers who think you should use who/whose to refer to people and animals only. [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whose-for-inanimate-objects)

Comment: Related: [Is it “a company who makes …” or “a company that makes…”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100607), ['Who' or 'which' in reference to companies](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138110), [“Managers are one group to which” vs. “managers are one group to whom”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88428)

Comment: A "goverment body"/company etc can be thought of as a single entity or a group of people - "who" fits the latter definition.  Strictly speaking, with this logic, you should say "the government body who **have** assigned", but this feels weird to me.

Comment: It's much simpler than that: "a government body," "a corporate body," "an organization," and so on are, as the OP already noted, inanimate and take *which,* not *who.* Unless the entity itself is referred to in such a way as to reflect it as a group of people (constituting the governement body, etc.). "The EPA, **which** has refused permission, ...;" but "The (members of the ) board of certification," **who** were unanimous in their opinion, ...." Also, "The police was on the look out ...; " and "The police (-men) were on the look out."

Comment: @sumelic We cannot oversimplify any more than that.

Comment: @sumelic: I agree that this is an interesting question, & researching it is a challenge (though a search with "who what" narrows it down a bit). But even the inclusion of a link to an inadequate Q&A and a comment that "this doesn't seem to help" would show effort and help avoid drive-by downvotes. Which, by the way, *I consciously avoid*, having been hugely discouraged by them in my first few weeks as a new member of this site (although a user of ELU for over 4 years).